# ¿Tamaño de letra fija con CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

Estoy desarrollando un reporte del lado del cliente generando un PDF en un sitio web pero tengo un inconveniente con el tamaño de la letra ya que deseo que esta sea fija y no cambien en ningún aspecto, ya que al modificar la propiedad del navegador (Chrome) tamaño mínimo de fuente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el reporte se descuadra en el PDF resultante lo cual causa inconvenientes, ya que si los usuario tienen un ajuste distinto al que viene por defecto en el navegador el reporte generado se modificara, lo que deseo hacer es definir en el CSS un font-size fijo y que no cambie si modifico esta propiedad del navegador.
He probado con diferentes medidas pero ninguna me funciona

```
.is-size-8 {
            font-size: 10.56px !important; 
            font-size: 2.8998mm !important;
            font-size: 0.28998cm !important;
           }
```

¿Esto es posible?, ¿Qué alternativas tengo?
Les agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: ¿Con que o como generas el PDF?  ¿O te refieres a imprimir a PDF?  Si es esto último no podras controlarlo

Comment: Actualmente utilizo las librerías HTML2CANVAS y JSPDF, pero tengo un inconveniente con la letra al momento de modificar esta propiedad del navegador

Comment: ¿Has probado poniendo los estilos en línea en lugar de en un CSS?

Comment: Si, pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: No se, eso lo vi en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014444/how-can-i-control-the-font-size-in-html2canvas  pero veo poca info al respecto... quizas deberias detectar si estan haciendo zoom antes de permitir la creación del pdf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers o con font-variant: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1661 ... pero vamos, que no tengo ni idea :-)  suerte!